# Ember js: TypeError: this.store.adapterFor is not a function inside component

Tags: ember.js

So I have different host url for production and development

I am trying to make a ajax post call inside a component, 
I have this to get the host from the store:

```
var host = this.store.adapterFor('application').get('host');
```

I have injected the dependency with this:

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Component.extend({
   store: Ember.inject.service(),
```

but I get this error

```
TypeError: this.store.adapterFor is not a function
```

Any help will be appreciated.

also here is my adapters/application.js

```
import DS from 'ember-data';
import ENV from "../config/environment";

export default DS.JSONAPIAdapter.extend({
    host: ENV.APP.API_HOST,
});
```

Comment: Injected services are lazy loaded, you need to use `this.get('store')`

Comment: @Kitler thanks, I'm new to ember so was confused and didn't google the right thing, thanks for clearing that up, helped a lot.